# "Error: [$parse:syntax] in angularjs dynamically creating checkbox

Tags: angularjs

```
input class="ng-pristine ng-valid" ng-value="{{type1}}" ng-model="data.chksuggst[type1]" type="checkbox">
```

I am getting error that mentioned in title please someone can solve this.
Thank you.

Comment: could you share it in fiddle ?

Comment: Thnx for quick reply but i've found the ans from below.
thanks anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do not use "{{ }}" syntax in ng- directives.

Please try:

```
<input class="ng-pristine ng-valid" ng-value="type1" ng-model="data.chksuggst[type1]" type="checkbox">
```

Comment: thnx it worked but can u explain what was the cause?

Comment: Because $scope.{{type1}} is a messed up syntax which is essentially where you're asking ng-value to find its value

Comment: Yes. Inside ng- directives you have access to $scope variables directly.